# Require a PHP Image Resizer/Cropping Script

Tags: php, image-processing, resize, crop

I am grabbing links to images and need to convert them on the fly to 72x108 to display on a website. The source images come from various resolutions, so cropping is required.

I know a moderate level of PHP so I can probably make something work for my needs, but was hoping for something that could be called by a url request. EG: mysite.com/thumbnail.php?src=http://anothersite.com/image.jpg&w=72&h=108

That would be ideal, it needs to support jpg/png.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to introduce a costly bottleneck rather than simply resize/crop the image server-side using GD?

Comment: Purchasing code from Stack Overflow requires a 50% up-front payment. The custom script that you have ordered is priced at GBP£1000. Cash or credit?

Comment: Wow thanks, i was just hoping for some suggestions. Even a more developed alternative to resizer.co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a really handy script for processing and uploading images that's been a top google result for forever. I used it years ago and it was really easy to implement. Looks like it was just updated a couple weeks ago too :)

http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm

This may be overkill, but if you check out the examples you can see there's a lot you can do with it. If you don't use it for this project, it might be worthwhile to try out for the next one.

Answer (score 0):

just read the image from the url with file_get_contents or using curl and use the php gd library to resize and crop the image as per your needs.

Go through the following links for more info:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

http://davidwalsh.name/download-urls-content-php-curl